# Delete an object inside an object reactjs redux?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a simple application with reactjs, redux; The database like this

```
const initialState = [
  {
    title: "List 1",
    id: 0,
    cards: [
      {
        id: 0,
        text: "Task 1",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Task 2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "List 2",
    id: 1,
    cards: [
      {
        id: 0,
        text: "Task 3",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Task 4",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The app has many lists. In many list has many cards, I want delete a card in a list
So in my listReducer.js. I created a delete reducer to delete a task like this.

```
case CONSTANTS.DELETE_CARD: {
      const { listId, id } = action.payload;
      return state.map((list) => {
        if (list.id === listId) {
          return {
            ...list,
            cards: list.cards.filter((card) => card.id !== id),
          };
        }
        return list;
      });
    }
```

But It not working correctly. What I am doing wrong?

the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/htactive-nhaptt/crud-trello?file=/src/reducers/listReducers.js:1466-1773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not with your reducer. I looked at your codesandbox example and added a few `console.log` and looks like everything gets updated correctly.

The problem is in the render function of your `List` component in `components/List.js`. Because you're not passing a unique key to `Card` component, React doesn't know what items have changed and it only sees a change in cards list lenght. So on re-render, it renders the old list up to the new length (hope it makes sense!) See here for more info on `keys`: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys.

You can fix the issue by passing a unique key to `Card` like this on line 72:

`return <Card key={card.id} id={card.id} listId={listId} text={card.text} />;`

Comment: You beat me ;-) so I upvote yours....but I think there is still a problem in his reducer : he is mutate it directly